# notification not fire on ios 12

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to convert my swift code to support IOS 10 and above but I did not get any notification this is my code

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "tried"
content.subtitle = "wg"
content.body = "any body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "name.caf"))

let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current,year: components.year , month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

I print pending notifications, there are pending notifications but not fired

```
<UNNotificationRequest: 0x60000314d650; identifier: C8BC936E-AD9B-4D7A-94D3-52D3233DE281, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x600000ad8780; title: tried, subtitle: wg, body: any body, summaryArgument: , summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: (null), sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x600001bdb900>,, trigger: <UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x600003f511a0; dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x6000008fd550>
    Calendar: <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x600003f51240>
    TimeZone: Asia/Riyadh (GMT+3) offset 10800
    Calendar Year: 2019
    Month: 6
    Day: 22
    Hour: 8
    Minute: 5, repeats: NO>>
```

Comment: Date seems to be 22nd ot June, so you won't see it until then, no?

Comment: BTW, I assume that you’ve also requested permission (e.g. see [Asking Permission to Use Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications)).

Comment: I asked for permission I find the problem in my answer blew

Answer (score 0):

What I find out that IOS did not schedule notification if you give it full date if the notification time in **same day**

If the notification in same day you have to give it the **hour and minute only**